# How to find a special superset of a set as given?

Tags: python

Using Python, I am trying to create a special superset of the list `lambdas = [20, 32, 18]` such that the set should be as following:

```
lambdasubs = [20, 32, 18, 20+32, 20+18, 32+18, 20+32+18] which is same as
lambdasubs = [20, 32, 18, 52, 38, 50, 70]
```

I know I can always start with:

```
lambdasubs = lambdas
```

for the first 3 elements, and then?

Comment: That's not a proper subset. That's not a subset at all; it's a superset generated by summing each nonempty element of the power set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to make all the `1`, `2`... `N` length combinations from your original list

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(itertools.combinations(lambdas, i)) for i in range(1, len(lambdas)+1)]
[[(20,), (32,), (18,)], [(20, 32), (20, 18), (32, 18)], [(20, 32, 18)]]
```

Then you can `sum` each of the inner `tuple` to add any combinations that have more than one element and flatten that list

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((sum(j) for j in itertools.combinations(lambdas, i)) for i in range(1, len(lambdas)+1)))
[20, 32, 18, 52, 38, 50, 70]
```

To be more clear about what's going on, this is roughly equivalent to the following more procedural code

```
import itertools
lambdas = [20, 32, 18]
values = []
for size in range(1, len(lambdas)+1):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(lambdas, size):
        values.append(sum(comb))

>>> print(values)
[20, 32, 18, 52, 38, 50, 70]
```

Comment: What if the values in lambdas are not integer?

Comment: Okay, I was just making a mistake. It also works for floats. Thanks.